# Mysql Sock Problem

Tags: mysql, socket

I'm having problem with this error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

It appears every few minutes but after few seconds everything is ok...

Have you guys any solution for that?

Comment: Version? Access method? (C, JDBC, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the error message the number 2 in parentheses is errno: No such file or directory

Who is removing the socket? I would find that out with with Linux **audit** facility. It is very helpful when diagnosing problems such as this.

Edited to add: Is your mysqld server process dying for some reason? It might remove the socket if it dies. Then the wrapper script re-starts the mysqld process and the socket gets re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps connection pool's connection timed out?
Or maybe too many connections?